# What is the best way of getting the timezone from the city, country that user selects?

Tags: php, javascript

I looked into javascript, and thought about using the client's clock, but it doesn't seem very reliable since the client's clock is out of my control.

I looked around for web services but wasn't lucky.

Basically what I want is to display a specific time (e.g. 9:00:00 GMT +4) in the user's timezone, based on location provided (city, country).

Thanks

Comment: almost every one uses one of the GeoIp versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this JavaScript tool [jsTimezoneDetect](https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect/wiki/Home) is what you need. It is very easy to use and it can detect a pretty big range of timezones. Besides, if you want to detect the timezone from the country and city that the user selected, I think you would need to store the whole Olson timezone database and make Ajax call to get what you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you're limiting the list of cities to the [cities supported by PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)  it's pretty easy, you can then use the [DateTimeZone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) class.

If you're allowing the user to choose any old city and want to work out the timezone from that then I'm pretty sure there isn't a maintained mapping file.

You could use a webservice to look up the latitude and longitude of a city and then plug that latitude &longitude into [Ask Geo](http://www.askgeo.com/) or a similar webservice. You'd need to ask the country too there's a Cairo in the USA and in Egypt.

Comment: [Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php) is an example of the usage.