# Convert ISO 3166-1 alpha-3 Country code to Timezone

Tags: timezone, iso, country-codes

Is there any library I can user to convert `ISO 3166-1 alpha-3 Country code` to its timezone?

Like `HKG` `->` `+0800`

Comment: Not every country code is convertable to a time zone, though

Comment: For example? Some countries have no timezone? 0.0 btw any method that can at least partially convert will still work.

Comment: Some countries have *multiple* timezones

Comment: I see. Thank you for your information

Comment: Can you add what platform you are working with? There's various libraries, e.g. for PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-time-zone-by-country-and-region.php you'll probably find that Googling `convert country to timezone <name of your platform>` will get you results

Comment: For JS, eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19783249/getting-time-zone-when-entering-state-and-country-time-zone-to-use-in-ics-file