# How to determine timezone if Country-Code, State and/or City is known?

Tags: javascript, time, timezone

How do I determine the timezone (in javascript) if Country-Code, State and City is known ?
For example: Country:US State CA is know

Comment: The dup link asks about PHP, but the question and answer are pretty much the same otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few libraries that include this information within them, one of this is https://www.npmjs.com/package/countryjs. Using their .info() you get the information of that zone, including timezone.

However, as mentioned in [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19783249/getting-time-zone-when-entering-state-and-country-time-zone-to-use-in-ics-file), this is hard since some states span multiple timezones.

Check this other duplicate, there are good answers there: [What is the best way of getting the timezone from the city, country that user selects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934757/what-is-the-best-way-of-getting-the-timezone-from-the-city-country-that-user-se)

As mentioned, [jsTimezoneDetect](https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect/wiki/Home) is a good resource.

Hope that helps.